# If routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); is mandatory, why isn't it setup once through IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I notice `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` is always setup whenever we create MVC applications.

If it is a mandatory thing, why don't we setup it once through IIS settings rather than doing it again and again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody said it was 'mandatory'. It makes excellent sense to be there by default, though. And if you don't want it, you can remove it.

Comment: I need this setting of course to prevent users from accessing my resources. Is there a case we allow users to have access to the resources?

Comment: You don't appear to understand what that line of code does. It does *not* block access to anything at all. It allows that matching URL to be requested, actually (because without it, the routing system would prevent it from being accessed because it won't match any valid routes, and there is no actual 'file' which would normally cause Routing to ignore a URL)

Comment: Yes, I don't know actually what it does. I am still reading the page 60 of Scott Hanselman' chapter 1 : NerdDinner. Thank  you.

Comment: @xport - It's fine not to know something; that's why this site is here. It just confused me when you said that you need that line of code to prevent users from accessing your resources; that seemed to suggest you thought you knew what it did.

Comment: In my mental model, it works like filtering requests that we usually do in IIS. For example, we prevent user from accessing some file extensions. :)

Comment: Nope; it excludes paths from the Routing system.